# Layout igraph object as fan [R]

Tags: r, igraph

I have a hierarchical **non-binary** tree structure that is represented as `igraph` object.

```
library(igraph)
df = data.frame(subregion = c("Africa", "Europe", "Asia", "Namibia", "Kenya", "Egypt", "Belgium", "China", "India"),
       region = c("World", "World", "World", "Africa", "Africa", "Africa", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia"))
df_graph = graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = F)
plot(df_graph, layout = layout_as_tree(df_graph, root = "World"))
```

[image]

There are three hierarchical levels with nodes on the same level being equally dissimilar. Now I want to layout this graph as a fan, just like you can do it with a dendrogram:

```
df_graph_cl = cluster_fast_greedy(df_graph)
plot_dendrogram(df_graph_cl, type = "fan")
```

[image]

However, the original relationships among nodes are not preserved in the dendrogram because it's a **binary** tree. Any idea on how too layout the graph as a fan without converting it to a dendrogram?

Comment: Generally dendrograms have binary splits and that's what most of the R plotting functions assume. And generally where the split is drawn is meaningful in the dendrogram. Why exactly are you trying to force your data into what seems like an incorrect visualization?

Comment: Thanks, MrFlick. The reason is because I have about 650 tips and want to use a "fan"-like layout. There does not seem to be such a layout option for ordinary graphs.

Comment: If your real goal is to draw a fan, then why didn't you state that? Why require the dendrogram first? I suggest you edit your question to make it clear what your actual desired output is rather than creating an intermediate "solution"

Comment: You're right. I rewrote the question to reflect my actual goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now came up with a work-around and thought I'd share it. The key was to convert the graph into [NEWICK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format) format. For that, I had to write a little [function](https://gist.github.com/ChrKoenig/2289006de68f26f04e3e7fa1eb7a683c) that performs depth first search on the graph and creates the NEWICK string.

Using the example data, I can now easily do:

```
library(phytools)
newick = graph_to_newick(df_graph, root = "World")
df_tree = collapse.singles(read.newick(text = newick))
plot(df_tree, type = "fan")
```

Which produces the desired output:

[image]